# How to break Lync / Cisco IP Softphone interaction when placing a call from Lync?

Tags: voip, lync

I have the following VoIP configuration on my Windows 8.1:

- a Lync 2013 client (connected to an OCS server)
- Cisco IP Phone (for PSTN calls)
- a speakerphone (speaker & microphone, namely a Jabra SPEAK 510 if this helps)

Everything works fine except one thing: whenever I initiate a call from Lync (to another Lync client), the Cisco IP Phone wakes up ready to place a call, sending the continuous dial tone (as if it was picked up).

I therefore have the call signal of Lync (and, later, my party) superimposed with the pick-up tone from Cisco. This makes a conversation impossible.

If I hang up the Cisco IP Phone, it closes both its (uninvited) session but also the Lync one (it is as if the Lync call was hang up).

There is therefore some kind of relationship between these two soft devices -- any idea where it sits?

Note: this does not happen the other way round - i.e. when placing a call from the Cisco phone.

Answer (score 2):

If headset has specific software install latest version, and update headset firmware. With Jabra headsets you can install Jabra Direct, update firmware, and it resolves these issues (most times).